# How to release memory of a retained object

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, xcode4, memory-leaks

This is one of my method.

```
- (void)getSearchResultsByKeyword:(NSString *)keyword 
                searchOptions:(NSArray *)searchOptions 
         searchGroupsInResult:(NSArray *)searchGroupsInResult
{
    _searchKeyword = [keyword retain];
    _searchOptions = [searchOptions retain];
    _searchGroupsInResult = [searchGroupsInResult retain];
    [_searchResultsGroups removeAllObjects];
    [_searchResultsGroupsIndexToNameMap removeAllObjects];
    _pageNo = 1;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationOnMainThreadName:SearchResultsRetrievingStartLodingNotification 
                                                                object:self];
    [_dataProvider startGettingSearchResultsByKeyword:self.searchKeyword 
                                    searchOptions:_searchOptions
                             searchGroupsInResult:_searchGroupsInResult
                                           pageNo:_pageNo
                                         delegate:self];
}
```

In my method I have called retain on the objects which are parameters. So I have owned the object and has increased the retain count. So my problem is, how do I decrease the retain count after the

```
[_dataProvider startGettingSearchResultsByKeyword:self.searchKeyword 
                                        searchOptions:_searchOptions
                                 searchGroupsInResult:_searchGroupsInResult
                                               pageNo:_pageNo
                                             delegate:self];
```

call. ( `[keyword release]` or `[_searchKeyword release]` ) ??

In my header file I have declared the `_searchOptions` as a private instance and `_searchKeyword` as a `readonly` property. In my implementation file, I have released both instances in `dealloc`.

I ran Analyze tool and it did not show this thing as an issue. But I have a doubt on it.

So, please show me a necessary way to work on this thing.

I'm working on XCode4 and iOS 4.3.

Thanks.

Comment: You release an object with `[object_address release]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jaydee3's answer is correct. I would add that you *really* should use @properties with synthesized accessors. Then, instead of setting your instance variables directly, use the accessor methods. That way you can encapsulate all of the memory management of your instance variables in the accessor methods. This has the advantage of being more readable, much less error prone, and makes your code easier to modify in the future.

So, in your .h (or in a class extension in your .m if the properties should be "private"):

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *searchKeyword;
```

In your .m:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    self.searchKeyword = nil;

    [super dealloc];
}

@synthesize searchKeyword = _searchKeyword;
```

Finally, in your `-getSearchResultsByKeyword:searchOptions:searchGroupsInResult:` method:

```
self.searchKeyword = keyword;
```

instead of

```
_searchKeyword = [keyword retain];
```

Now you don't have to worry about releasing *or* retaining `searchKeyword`. The setter method generated by the @synthesize directive will take care of it for you. I suggest reading Apple's documentation on [Declared Properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html).

Answer (score 2):

Since you are assigning to an ivar, you have to retain it. This is correct.
Releasing it within dealloc is also correct. But thats not enough. Two things:

1) It's better to copy strings, rather than retain them. So use `_searchKeyword = [keyword copy];`. (This is also retained. So the retainCount is 1 after that.)

2) Also there is a problem, when you call your method the second time. That is the point, where you *do have* a leak. You are assigning a new value to your ivar `_searchKeyword', dismissing the pointer to the old keyword, which is still retained. So before assigning the new one, release the old one also.

Example:

```
[_searchKeyword release];
_searchKeyword = [keyword copy];
```

If you copy it, this is good, but if you only retain, it would be even better to do it like that (in case both reference the same object):

```
[keyword retain];
[_searchKeyword release];
_searchKeyword = keyword;
```

Comment: thanx jaydee3. Your answer is absolutely helpful. But I have another question. When the  ' -getSearchResultsByKeyword:searchOptions:searchGroupsInResult: ' method call at the first time, ' _searchKeyword ' 's retain count is 0. So after the ' [_searchKeyword release] ' call, what will happen ?

Comment: The absolute retain count is meaningless;  The result of `copy` is a +1 retain count.  The actual retain count might be vastly different.

Comment: Unfortunately, @bbum, there's a doc bug that leads people to cite a copied object's retain count as exactly one: "Copying an object not only duplicates it but almost always resets its retain count to one" ["How Memory Management Works"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW10), right below figure 2.5 in Cocoa Fundamentals.

Comment: **almost always** is the key, though... should be re-worded.  Bug filed.

Comment: Anyhow to answer to your question. On nil objects you can send any message without worrying. So, as your _searchKeyword is nil in the beginning, you can send release on it and nothing will happen.

Answer (score 0):

When there are two objects that are pointers to the same thing, it doesn't matter which one you call release on.  The thing pointed at is where the reference count gets decremented.

Given you've released it in one place, and the analyzer isn't complaining, you don't have a problem.